# How to write custom serializer for entity with MobogDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to get a document from database, but I can't do it in a desirable way.
It seems handy to use this approach to retrieve data:

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id == new ObjectId(id), true);
var result = await coll.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

But in this case `InvalidOperationException` is thrown when executing `Find` method. Exception text:
`Unable to determine the serialization information for x => (x.Id == new ObjectId(value(BookService.Controllers.ImportController+<>c__DisplayClass1_0).id)).`

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, when I use this filter:

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(id));
```

there are no any exceptions and result contains proper entity instances.
It seems that I need to implement custom serializer to determine that when `x.Id` is used it means to search by `_id` field, but I don't know how to do that. Or maybe there are some other ways to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id == new ObjectId(id), true);
```

Change it to this and it should fix your problem

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, new ObjectId(id));
```

I always represent ObjectId as string in my C# models and use BsonRepresentation as an attribute to ensure correct serialization

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
[BsonId]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

That way your queries just look like this:

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
var result = await coll.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Or even better

```
var result = await coll.Find(x => x.Id == id).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry for not anaswering for so long. Thanks, man. Your solution is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm glad I could help